# Microsoft Access connection to MYOB ODBC developer mode

Tags: odbc, myob

I am running 32-bit Microsoft Access on Windows 8.1 and MYOB Premier 19.10

Have no problem setting up a 32 bit DSN and accessing MYOB in read only mode from Access.

Have installed developer key and have tested connection using TestConnection from MYOB. Test OK

When I now try to link to a MYOB table, I get a ODBC call failed - Cannot launch MYOB #20066 error. Have tried changing MYOB and Access to XP compatibility mode - still the same.

I also get the same error running on a Windows 7 machine.

Can someone please help.

gary

Answer (score 1):

1. I am not familiar with Access, but if you are going to use a DSN to write to MYOB ODBC tables your connection string must look something like "DSN=YourMyobDsnName;ACCESS_TYPE=READ_WRITE". If Access does not allow you to add parameters to the connection string it's probably not going to work.
2. Another way connect to the company file is to use an ADO connection string. It would look something like "Driver={MYOAU1001};TYPE=MYOB;UID=Administrator; PWD=MyPassword;DATABASE=C:\PathToYourCompanyFile\CompanyFile.myo; HOST_EXE_PATH=C:\PathToTheMyobExecutable\MYOBP.exe;
   ACCESS_TYPE=READ_WRITE;DRIVER_COMPLETION=DRIVER_NOPROMPT;KEY=AAAA...DDDD". Your paths and credentials will of course differ, as may the version of MYOB ODBC you are using. 10.01 is the most recent version in AU.
3. Following your comments I looked into it and now understand this capability is not available in Access. A common approach is to create a small executable that exchanges information between MYOB v19 ledgers and whatever it is you need to integrate with. Again, I am not an expert but it seems to me that you could use VBA in Access to accomplish this. VBA can use the ADO libraries.

Comment: Access simply uses the DSN definitions in ODBC32. I have no idea of how to bind Access to an ADO connection string.

Comment: @Gary v19 and older MYOB ledger systems have an underlying ISAM database. The ODBC driver does not connect directly to the database, but uses import and export services exposed by the executable. This means that while you might be able to link "tables" in Access (they're really a kind of view) to read, you may not be able to write back to them.

Answer (score 0):

I had to disable UAC on Windows 10 to get MYOB to launch via ODBC:

https://superuser.com/questions/83677/disabling-uac-on-windows-7